# How do I make SpaCy choose noun chunks separated by "and" or "," as one

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I'm sorry about the title, I really didn't know how to phrase it, but hopefully this example will make it clear.

Basically,

**For the following sentence:**

Ashley and Brian are drinking water.

I want the noun chunk to be "Ashley and Brian" instead it is, "Ashley", "Brian"

**Another example is:**

Types of clothes include shirts, pants and trousers.

I want the noun chunk to be "shirts, pants and trousers" instead of "shirts" "pants" "trousers"

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is not a noun chunk. The `conjuncts` feature is closer to what you want.

This might not work for complex sentences, but at least it'll cover your examples and typical cases.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

texts = [
        "Ashley and Brian are drinking water.",
        "Types of clothes include shirts, pants and trousers.",
        ]

for text in texts:
    print("-----")
    print(text)
    checked = 0
    doc = nlp(text)
    for tok in doc:
        if tok.i < checked: continue
        if tok.pos_ not in ('NOUN', 'PROPN'): continue

        if tok.conjuncts:
            print(doc[tok.left_edge.i:tok.right_edge.i+1])
            checked = tok.right_edge.i + 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (It still doesn't include the noun chunks, but with a little bit of code I think i can fix that. Thanks :)